# Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined , joomla 2.5.7 error on Chrome

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-article

I am working with Joomla 2.5.7, when trying to add or modify an article I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

But this only happens with Chrome, if I try to create an article using FireFox then it goes ok.

Does any one of you have had this error before?

Seems Chrome doesn't load properly the tiny_mce.js:1 file and get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

before get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

, I have uploaded again the file but still get the error and still works only on FF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simpliest way to solve this and other issues with the common Joomla editors is to move to JCE (Joomla Content Editor) which can be download from: http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/

Answer (score 0):

When none of the editors works in the joomla administrator, you only see a textarea and there is an undefined error in the javascript console, it is posible that you don't have the live_site parameter set in the configuration.php. It should be an absolute url to the joomla index, for example:

> public $live_site = 'http://www.example.com/example';

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem as you.

In chrome, clear all your browsing data, and restart chrome.

The problem will be solved.